# Android/Java, Settings.System.canWrite(context) error

Tags: java, android

I need to manage Brightness.
After reading some topics here, I tried this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings;

public static boolean canWriteSettings(){
    Context context;
    if (Settings.System.canWrite(context) == false){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    return Settings.System.canWrite(context);
}
```

But I got an error to line if (Settings.System.canWrite(context)... on context ???
Is somebody to clarify?

The log

:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\Mes Projets Mobile\VR-Guide_SQLite\Android\Generation\src\com\eleana\vrguide\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_ProceduresGlobales.java:620: error: variable context might not have been initialized
    if (Settings.System.canWrite(context) == false){
                                 ^
1 error
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Many thanks.

Comment: post your error  log ^_^

Comment: `context` is null.

Comment: initialize context.

Comment: Thanks,
I do Context context = getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

Error happens here --> `(Settings.System.canWrite(context) == false)` .
The reason being is because you haven't initialized the `context` variable, in other words, it's null.